# Redirect output of log into net core console window

Tags: c#, .net-core

In `net core` there is nice log console window. I would like to use it but i develop using `.NET framework`. I use `Serilog` to log data into `.txt` and `.json` files. Is there anyway to have that `console window` which would print nicely in color from that log files during progrm debug?

Comment: Serilog has a [console sink](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-console)

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski i got this installed but console is not showing up when program runs. I got  .WriteTo.Console()      and WriteToFile but only WriteToFile seems to work

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski ok i did WriteTo.Debug and i see logs in Output window. Is there any chance to have it in console window to have coloring of log type messages thats what i am intrested

Answer (score 0):

I can't imagine there is any way to do that without jumping through significant hoops. What I do is log to a .log file, and then have that open in Visual Studio Code which will automatically apply coloured highlighting. You could then add the 'Log Viewer' extension to VS Code which will allow 'tailing' the log file and other things.